# Getting date range as user input on Default.ASPX and drawing a table on ReportPage.ASPX using SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedures with parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Sales Reports Comparision Panel on `default.aspx`

```
Start Date:              |Date |
End Date                 |End Date| 
Compare to this year:    |2013|         <-- A Dropdown Menu from database

|Submit|             |Reset Form|
```

I have a `ViewSales.aspx` page which I will need to draw a table from the database.

I have added `Server.Transfer("ViewSales.aspx.cs", true);` to submit button control from `default.aspx.cs` to transfer the state.

Currently, there is a GridView data table on the `ViewReports.aspx` with a `SqlConnection` source. Connection is just pulling the hard data from the database with a query and drawing the table.

Now I am trying to write a stored procedure that takes start and end dates as parameters and gives the rows that between the range and I am stuck here. Whats wrong with my stored procedure?

I also will be very happy to get any comments for evaluating the main logic of the application.

Thanks

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Simmons,Madeline>
-- Create date: <4/30/2013>
-- Description: <This stored procedure pulls the sales wihtin a range>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE <Get_Sales_Within_Range, sysname, Get_Sales_Within_Range> 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    <@StartDate, sysname, @p1> <Start_Date_Data_Type, , smalldate> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
    <@EndDate, sysname, @p2> <End_Date_Data_Type, , smalldate> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT <@StartDate, sysname, @p1>, <@EndDate, sysname, @p2>
    FROM Sales_Table 
    WHERE 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetReportsWithinRange
    @Start_Date smalldatetime, 
    @End_Date smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  *  --You can define columns that you want to pull
    FROM    dbo.Sales_Report
    WHERE   Sales_Date >= @Start_Date AND
        Sales_Date <= @End_Date
END
GO
```

Don't forget to test your stored procedures.